# Async Await javascript

Tags: javascript

How i can run `runApp()` function when I click submit? This code below makes my `runApp` function run before click, but I want to input the value from the form.

```js
const login = (username, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let result
    let err
    if (username == "angga" || password != null) {
      result = "Login sukses, anda menuju ke halaman utama"
      resolve(result)
    } else {
      err = "Login gagal, username tidak ada !!!"
      reject(err)
    }

  }, 0)
})

const mainmenu = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("biodata.html")
  }, 0)
})

const runApp = async function() {
  const getUsername = await username()
  alert(`username : ${getUsername}`)
  const getPassword = await password()
  alert(`password : ${getPassword}`)
  const resultLogin = await login(getUsername, getPassword)
  alert(`${resultLogin}`)
  const resultMainMenu = await mainmenu()
  return resultMainMenu
}

const username = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let usernameFromBrowser = document.querySelector("#username").value;
    resolve(usernameFromBrowser)
  }, 0)
})

const password = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let passwordFromBrowser = document.querySelector("#password").value;
    resolve(passwordFromBrowser)
  }, 0)
})

runApp()
  .then((getResolve) => {
    // window.location.href = `${getResolve}`
  })
  .catch((getReject) => {
    alert(`${getReject}`)
  })
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" value="angga" placeholder="Masukkan username">

  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" value="123456" placeholder="Masukkan password">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="test()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Help me please, it's homework.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Answer (score 0):

Let the run app() be wrap in the function declaration of test ()    ..
As shown below

Test(){
runApp()
.then((getResolve) => { window.location.href = `${getResolve}` })
.catch((getReject) => { alert(`${getReject}`) })

}

Comment: i did this but the value is not got from front end only the username, i just hardcode the value from front end

Answer (score -1):

From what I see, it appears that runApp is invoked once the JS file has loaded and the onSubmit event seems to call a function that doesn't exist.

I would suggest making the JS file more modular.

Here are couple of things that could help you out though:

Option 1:
HTML

```
    <button type="submit" ... onClick="() => runApp().then(...).catch(...)">...
```

Option 2:
HTML

```
    <button type="submit" ... onClick="startApplication">...
```

JS

```
    ...
    function startApplication() {
       runApp()
       .then((getResolve) => { window.location.href = `${getResolve}` })
       .catch((getReject) => { alert(`${getReject}`) })
       // other things 
    }
    ...
```